# Size of derived template class at compile time in base class

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I have an existing architecture that uses polymorphic containers to hold the instances of derived template classes. Now I need to override an operator within the base class and declare a type with the size of the derived classes at compile time.
The architecture looks like the following diagram:
[image]

I already tried a forward declaration of the template classes within the base class header but without success. And I also tried to make a template out of the base class to get the class type but this doesnt work with the polymorphic containers.

thanks in advance

Comment: Seems like you have a design problem. You need all possible options of `Model`? Even the ones you don't know about at this stage?

Comment: When an inherited class knows its inheriting classes there is already a design problem, with template classes this seems worst. Why do you need to know the size at compile time rather than at execution time ( `virtual size_t sizeOf() const = 0;` on _Model_ and implemented on _ModelA_ and _ModelB_ )

Comment: Seems that behind this there is an interesting question, but it is not clear.

Comment: I know that the architecture is worse but it was given. I need it at compile time because I need to use a template class within the overridden operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your design is, that there is no way the `Model` class can know the size of it's derived classes if it doesn't know which class is deriving it.
As you correctly stated, making the `Model` a class template itself will prevent you from creating a dynamic container of `Models`.

To solve this problem you can add a layer of static polymorphism (a.k.a CRTP) to achieve what you want.

The idea is to derive `Model` from a templated base class `ModelCRTPBase` which then delegates the interface functionality to the actual implementations.

Obviously it's still not the `Model` class that knows the size of it's children, but the `ModelCRTPBase`. But as the `Model` serves only as polymorphic interface class and all the common functionality of the models is in `ModelCRTPBase` (which knows the size at compile time) that should be not a problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>


class Model {

public:
    virtual ~Model() {}
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

template<typename Derived>
class ModelCRTPBase : public Model {

    Derived& derived() {
        return static_cast<Derived&>(*this);
    }

public:

    static size_t  size() {
        return sizeof(Derived);
    }

    void print() override  {
        std::cout << "print Base, size = " << size() << '\n';
        derived().print_impl();
    }

};

template <typename T>
class ModelA : public ModelCRTPBase<ModelA<T>> {

public:

    void print_impl() {
        std::cout << "ModelA<" << typeid(T{}).name() << ">\n";
    }
};

template <typename T>
class ModelB : public ModelCRTPBase<ModelB<T>> {

    int payload;

public:

    void print_impl() {
        std::cout << "ModelB<" << typeid(T{}).name() << ">\n";
    }
};
int main() {

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Model>> vec;
    vec.push_back(std::make_shared<ModelA<int>>());
    vec.push_back(std::make_shared<ModelB<float>>());

    vec[0]->print();
    vec[1]->print();

}
```

Outputs:

```
print Base, size = 8
ModelA<i>
print Base, size = 16
ModelB<f>
```